# How to update textview in fragment after preference has changed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-preferences

I need to update two textviews in fragment after user change preferences. I have already look for a lot of similar questions, but it wont help me. I even try to update all aplication every time, but I'm sure it's not the best solution.
Will appreciate any help.

**AppPreferenceActivity.java**

```
public class AppPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();

    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
        }
    }
}
```

**WeatherFragment.java**
(I cut the code for conveniences)

```
    public class WeatherFragment extends Fragment implements Constants {

    TextView currentTemperatureField;
    TextView pressureField;
    //...


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weather, container, false);
        currentTemperatureField = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.current_temperature_field);
        pressureField = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pressure_field);

        //...

        weatherAdapter = new WeatherAdapter(getContext(), weather);
        ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(weatherAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        updateWeatherData(new CityPreference(getActivity()).getCity());

        sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        tempPref = sharedPrefs.getString("tempPref", "Celsius");
        pressurePref = sharedPrefs.getString("pressurePref","mmHg");

        //...

    }

    private void renderWeather(JSONObject json){
        try {
            //...

            if(pressurePref.equals("mmHg")) {
                pressureField.setText(String.format("%.0f", (main.getDouble("pressure") / 1.333)) + " mmHg");
            }else{
                pressureField.setText(String.format("%.0f", main.getDouble("pressure")) + " hPa");
            }

            if(tempPref.equals("Celsius")) {
                currentTemperatureField.setText(String.format("%.1f", main.getDouble("temp")) + " ℃");
            }else{
                currentTemperatureField.setText(String.format("%.1f", (main.getDouble("temp")*1.8+32)) + " ℉");
            }

            //...

        }catch(Exception e){
            //...
        }
    }  

}
```

**UPD**
Thank to @beeb. I have already use OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //weatherFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/weather.ttf");
    updateWeatherData(new CityPreference(getActivity()).getCity());

    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    tempPref = sharedPrefs.getString("tempPref", "Celsius");
    pressurePref = sharedPrefs.getString("pressurePref","mmHg");

    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
            Log.e("WeatherActivity: ","preferences have changed");
            //Implementation
        }
    };

    sharedPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
}
```

but my problem is still "Implementation". I have no idea how to set new data to fragment's textview.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing Fragment like this adopt following approach by making an instance.

```
 MyPreferenceFragment myPreferenceFragment;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myPreferenceFragment = new MyPreferenceFragment()
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, myPreferenceFragment).commit();

    }
```

then make a method in your fragment to update the textView

```
publich void updateText(String text)
{
   textView.setText(text);
}
```

and call this method when you want to update the text like this:

```
myPreferenceFragment.updateText(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `SharedPreferences.onSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` in your `WeatherFragment`.

```
listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    // Implementation
  }
};

prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and came across this question. What fixed it for me was placing the code in the onResume method of the fragment. This is useful when the fragment containing your view object is not in the same activity as your settings menu.

```
public void onResume() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        boolean status = prefs.getBoolean("key", true);

        TextView statusView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.status);


        if (status){
            statusView.setText("Active");
        }else{
            statusView.setText("Disabled");
        }


        super.onResume();
}
```